# Empty grouping during Python regex evaluation

Tags: python, regex

Learning regex for python. I want to thank Jerry for his initial help on this problem. I tested this regex:

```
(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[,;]\s*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?
```

at http://regex101.com/ and it finds what I am looking for, which is the four words that come before a comma in a sentence and the four words after a comma. If there are three two words before the comma at the beginning of the sentence it cannot crash. The test sentence I am using is:

```
waiting for coffee, waiting for coffee and the charitable crumb.
```

right now the regex returns:

```
[('waiting', 'for', 'coffee', '', 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and')]
```

I can't quite understand why the fourth member of the set is empty. What I want is for the regex to only return the 3 before the comma and the 4 after the comma in this instance, but in the event that there are four words before the comma, I want it to return four.  I know that regex varies between languages, is this something I am missing in python?

Comment: What do you mean, "crash"? I don't see anything crashing here. "Return four" doesn't make much sense, either. Could you try to write with more precision?

Comment: ...and if you're asking about a problem with Python code, please show the actual Python code you're running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *optional* groups:

```
(\bw+\b)?
```

The question mark makes that an optional match. But Python will always return *all* groups in the pattern, and for any group that didn't match anything, an empty value (`None`, usually) is returned instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> example = 'waiting for coffee, waiting for coffee and the charitable crumb.'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[,;]\s*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)?')
>>> pattern.search(example).groups()
('waiting', 'for', 'coffee', None, 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and')
```

Note the `None` in the output, that's the 4th word-group before the comma not matching anything because there are only 3 words to match. You must've used `.findall()`, which explicitly returns *strings*, and the pattern group that didn't match is thus represented as an empty string instead.

Remove the question marks, and your pattern won't match your input example until you add that required 4th word before the comma:

```
>>> pattern_required = re.compile(r'(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)[,;]\s*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)')
>>> pattern_required.findall(example)
[]
>>> pattern_required.findall('Not ' + example)
[('Not', 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and')]
```

If you need to match between 2 and 4 words, but do *not* want empty groups, you'll have to make *one* group match multiple words. You cannot have a variable number of groups, regular expressions do not work like that.

Matching multiple words in one group:

```
>>> pattern_variable = re.compile(r'(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*((?:\b\w+\b[^a-z]*){1,3})[,;]\s*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)[^a-z]*(\b\w+\b)')
>>> pattern_variable.findall(example)
[('waiting', 'for coffee', 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and')]
>>> pattern_variable.findall('Not ' + example)
[('Not', 'waiting for coffee', 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and')]
```

Here the `(?:...)` syntax creates a *non*-capturing group, one that does not produce output in the `.findall()` list; used here so we can put a quantifier on it. `{1,3}` tells the regular expression we want the preceding group to be matched between 1 and 3 times.

Note the output; the second group contains a variable number of words (between 1 and 3).

Comment: Martijn, if I do use regex here, how to I fix this problem. Is there a way to make this work without producing null strings?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've got an answer as to how to sort out your regex, I'd point out that in Python - stuff like this is normally much more easily done, and readable via using builtin string functions, eg:

```
s = 'waiting for coffee, waiting for coffee and the charitable crumb.'
before, after = map(str.split, s.partition(',')[::2])
print before[-4:], after[:4]
# ['waiting', 'for', 'coffee'] ['waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and']
```

Comment: Only use regex when there is no other option. There is definitely another option here.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the response. In this example can you use multiple partitions? say you wanted to look for both a comma and a semi-colon, could you include both?

Comment: @EnglishGrad `str.partition` works on single characters, if you wanted to split on multiple characters,then you'd use `re.split('[;,]', s, maxsplit=1)`

Comment: Jon, I think I will use this method. Can you explain what the '[::2]' does?

Comment: @EnglishGrad `str.partition` will always return a 3-tuple.... the bit before, the bit it's splitting on, and the bit after... The `[::2]` is slicing syntax that in this case, takes the first and every 2nd item (for a 3-tuple, this = first and last) - eg: `r = [1, 2, 3]; print r[::2]; #[1, 3]` (aka. the bit before, and bit after the split character)

Answer (score 0):

When you've already got a regex that's that long and convoluted I **highly** suggest you don't try fixing your problem by adding more regex. It will only end in tears. If you want to get rid of that empty group I would consider just running:

```
filter(None, regex_return)
```

On the answer you get back.

For example:

```
test = ('waiting', 'for', 'coffee', '', 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and')
print filter(None, test)
>>> ('waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'waiting', 'for', 'coffee', 'and')
```

Which I believe does what you want.

Comment: That's just a bandaid, though. If you consider yourself competent, you should investigate /why/ a result occurs, and this has less to do with the regex itself, and more to do with the regex implementation.

Comment: @Arafangion You're right, the fix is to stop using regex altogether, but for developer time this is a million times easier than debugging regex. Probably shoulda gone the whole nine yards and just gotten rid of the regex, but I also really like filter and I think it's a good intro to the feature for someone new to the language.

Comment: @Arafangion, I agree that it is the implementation, which means my programming, but I do not know regex well enough to fix it. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: If you look at the other answers here, you'll find that the issue actually has *nothing* to do with the regular expression, and *everything* to do with understanding the language frameworks provided. As such, it is highly worthwhile to understand what is going on.

Comment: @EnglishGrad: Your regex is perfectly fine. See the other answers to how you can address it.